# Does anybody know where this rule of thumb came from? Rule of them: embedding vector dimension should be the 4th root of the number of categories

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-engineering, embeddings

I was taking an online ML course and the lecturer said that a rule of thumb for choosing the number of dimensions when embedding categorical data is the following

`embedding vector dimension should be the 4th root of the number of categories`

The lecturer worked for Google and when I looked on the internet for this I only found a Google blog which quickly mentioned it [google blog link](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html). I'm guessing it's something that they came up with at Google but was wondering if somebody else has maybe seen it in a research paper.

Answer (score 0):

google has published a word embedding that has embedding dimension of 300. Following the rule you have given it should have trained on $300^4 = 8.1*10^9$ words. If google is using ngrams instead of just words, then it seems plausible.

Comment: Do you mean Google might be using words + n-grams?

Comment: Maybe frequent ngrams, i.e., well known phrases.

Comment: 4th root, not to the power of 4 - as in, a square root of a square root.

Comment: @NL23codes Roots are the inverse of powers. There is nothing wrong here.